# Emacs -fs (fullscreen)

Tags: emacs, nvidia, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to use emacs in fullscreen mode with a decent font.  I have an nvidia-based laptop running Ubuntu. When it first loads, the font is huge think 16pt font.  I used the menu options to set a decent font (8pt).

Now when I run emacs in fullscreen mode, it adjusts the window sort of for the huge font then loads my 8pt font.  Now half of my screen is the minibuffer.  How do I correctly set the font so that I can use fullscreen mode.

I have tried specifying displaysize in my x config and X does not start.  I hear theres something else you need to do for nvidia drivers... but not sure how that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following (from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen) in my .emacs:

```
(defun toggle-fullscreen (&optional f)
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-value (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)))
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen
                         (if (equal 'fullboth current-value)
                             (if (boundp 'old-fullscreen) old-fullscreen nil)
                           (progn (setq old-fullscreen current-value)
                                  'fullboth)))))

(global-set-key [f11] 'toggle-fullscreen)

;; Make new frames fullscreen by default. Note: this hook doesn't do
;; anything to the initial frame if it's in your .emacs, since that file is
;; read _after_ the initial frame is created.
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'toggle-fullscreen)
```

Then F11 will toggle fullscreen on/off.

Comment: quite similar to mine ... but what does the add-hook do?

Comment: It executes `toggle-fullscreen` each time `make-frame` is called.

Comment: I'm going to have to give you the answer flag for this really cool snippet.  It does not resolve starting emacs -fs, but it works great after emacs has already loaded.  It should be noted this is tied to the monitor for some reason.  If I do it on my 2nd monitor it works very crappy.  I'm starting to like emacs better for windows, these bugs/features are extremely annoying.  Why would I ever want to tie myself to monitor specifications?

Answer (score 3):

This is tough since I can't replicate the problem on my machine. I just add -fs and it seems to work. If you just want more real estate... do these work for you:

- ditch the menu/toolbar

  - add `(menu-bar-mode 0)` and `(tool-bar-mode 0)` to .emacs
  - start up and maximze
  - you should just have the regular DE frame but nothing else
  - toggle from emacs using `M-x menu-bar-mode` and `M-x tool-bar-mode` as needed

---

- manually fullscreen emacs

  - I can just start emacs, right click the window bar and choose fullscreen from xfce
  - I have F11 set to do this, but it doesn't seem to work from emacs (emacs seems to try and interpret it as a key binding rather than passing the key to the DE)
  - if this works, perhaps find a binding in your DE that emacs doesn't care about and just maximize normally

---

- combine the two

  - I start emacs regularly (`/usr/bin/emacs`)
  - I disabled both tool-bar-mode and menu-bar-mode disabled
  - I manually fullscreen with a right mouse click on the window bar
  - I get [THIS](http://sites.google.com/site/jwhendytank/home/emacs-fs.png)
  - that's the entire screen, not just a shot of the window contents

What do you think of those ideas? Sorry I can't help more with Ubuntu and/or nvidia. No experience and tough if one can't replicate the problem! Maybe if emacs starts regularly for you the above can help achieve close (or fully) what you're hoping for.

Comment: I think the problem is related to emacs dependence on my millimeter sepcification.  As you can see in the 2nd answer, he provided a copy/paste of a script for going fullscreen.  This works on my laptop but not to attached monitor.